# Count number of times that an item occurred in each of multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to read a table and create another table that counts how many times a unique ID occurs in multiple specific columns.

For example, I have a table where each row shows a transaction, with a userId identifying the role of each person.

```
buyer      <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C")
seller     <- c("C", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A")
negotiator <- c("B", "C", "D", "D", "A", "B")

df <- data.frame(buyer, seller, negotiator)
df
#    buyer seller negotiator
#  1     A      C          B
#  2     A      B          C
#  3     B      C          D
#  4     A      B          D
#  5     B      C          A
#  6     C      A          B
```

I would then like to create a table that counts how many times a userId fulfilled a role in the transactions.

```
#   id  asBuyer  asSeller  asNegotiator
#    A        3         1             1
#    B        2         2             2
#    C        1         3             1
#    D        0         0             2
```

Would I need to create different dataframes and then merge?

Answer (score 5):

You can first melt your data then tabulate it. For example

```
dd<-reshape2::melt(df,0)
xtabs(~value+variable,dd)
#      variable
# value buyer seller negotiator
#     A     3      1          1
#     B     2      2          2
#     C     1      3          1
#     D     0      0          2
```

Comment: What is the 0 being passed to?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't thought of `melt(df,0)` before. :) In case one has no `reshape2` and `df` columns are of type character, maybe `with(setNames(stack(df), c("id", "as")), xtabs(~id+as))`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The 0 goes to the `id.vars` parameter. In this case, there is no variable that represent each row other than the row index itself.

Comment: Hmm. That's an error in `data.table`. Could you elaborate on how that works, exactly?

Comment: @MichaelChirico It appears to do the same thing as you have done in your answer: `melt(df, measure.vars=names(df)) == melt(df,0)`

Comment: @MrFlick Please comment on my simple solution below.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `data.table`:

## update inspired by MrFlick

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(melt(df, measure.vars = names(df)), value ~ variable)
#    value buyer seller negotiator
# 1:     A     3      1          1
# 2:     B     2      2          2
# 3:     C     1      3          1
# 4:     D     0      0          2
```

You could add `fun.aggregate = length` as an argument to `dcast` to suppress the warning message. And you could add `value.name = "id"` as an argument to `melt` if you prefer that column to be named `id`.

## original, longer answer

```
setDT(df)

outDT <- data.table(id = unique(unlist(df)))

invisible(
  sapply(names(df), function(jj)
    outDT[df[ , .N, by = jj], 
          #set the name you desire by pasting;
          #  could use a regex or substr to 
          #  for the first letter capital if need be
          (jj2 <- paste0("as", jj)) := i.N,
          #merge id to the count column
          on = c(id = jj)
          clean-up: missed observations were NA, set to 0
          ][is.na(get(jj2)), (jj2) := 0])
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using only base R (probably slower than other approaches) :

```
lst <- lapply(names(df), function(col) as.data.frame(table(df[[col]]),responseName=col))

mergeAll <- function(x,y) merge(x,y,all=TRUE)

res <- Reduce(f=mergeAll, lst)
names(res)[1] <- 'id'
res[is.na(res)] <- 0

> res
  id buyer seller negotiator
1  A     3      1          1
2  B     2      2          2
3  C     1      3          1
4  D     0      0          2
```

Comment: somewhat similar one-liner: `do.call(cbind,lapply(df,function(L) table(factor(L,levels(unlist(df))))))`

Comment: @MaratTalipov: great idea, using `unlist(df)` to create all possible values in order to use `cbind` and not `merge`! +1

Comment: @MaratTalipov: you should post your own answer IMO ;)

Comment: @digEmAll I also tried to use base R. Please comment on my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many R wizards here.

Here is my simple solution using basic R with just `ddply` (to create "count group by" tables) and `merge` (to perform outer join).

```
# Create data frame for buyer count
dfBuyer <- ddply(df, c("buyer"), summarise, count=length(seller))
colnames(dfBuyer) <- c("id", "asBuyer")

dfBuyer
#    id asBuyer
#  1  A       3
#  2  B       2
#  3  C       1


# Create data frame for seller count
dfSeller <- ddply(df, c("seller"), summarise, count=length(buyer))
colnames(dfSeller) <- c("id", "asSeller")

dfSeller
#    id asSeller
#  1  A        1
#  2  B        2
#  3  C        3


# Create data frame for negotiator count
dfNegotiator <- ddply(df, c("negotiator"), summarise, count=length(seller))
colnames(dfNegotiator) <- c("id", "asNegotiator")

dfNegotiator
#    id asNegotiator
#  1  A            1
#  2  B            2
#  3  C            1
#  4  D            2


# merge() apparently can merge only two dataframes at a time,
# so to merge three dataframes, merge the first two and then
# the third. Use "all=TRUE" to perform outer join.

# Merge buyer and seller
dfBuyerSellerMerged <- merge(x=dfBuyer, y=dfSeller, by="id", all=TRUE)

# Merge buyer and seller and negotiator
dfBuyerSellerNegotiatorMerged <- merge(x=dfBuyerSellerMerged, y=dfNegotiator, by="id", all=TRUE) 

dfBuyerSellerNegotiatorMerged
#   id asBuyer asSeller asNegotiator
# 1  A       3        1            1
# 2  B       2        2            2
# 3  C       1        3            1
# 4  D      NA       NA            2


# Remove NAs.
dfBuyerSellerNegotiatorMerged[is.na(dfBuyerSellerNegotiatorMerged)] <- 0

dfBuyerSellerNegotiatorMerged
#   id asBuyer asSeller asNegotiator
# 1  A       3        1            1
# 2  B       2        2            2
# 3  C       1        3            1
# 4  D       0        0            2
```

Comment: Your solution is just fine however it is 'hard-coded' to your particular problem. For example, if your input data frame had different column names or the number of columns, you would have to rewrite your code. I would suggest to look into the @digEmAll's solution which has the same logic as your solution but is more universal.      PS: 'base R' code should not need any additional packages, while your code requires the package 'plyr' (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Yep, as @MaratTalipov correctly said this is very similar to my solution; the main difference is that my code is more generic and if you add a new column to the initial data.frame you won't need to change anything. In fact I used `lapply` to perform counting on each column and `Reduce` to call merge multiple times. Also you used `ddply` from `plyr` package, so is not strictly base R. Anyway I don't see any particular problem in your approach ;)